# What is the correct traduction for "capitalizations" (for words)?

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-término

Writing a simple sentence I got the question of, what is the traduction of the word "capitalization". For words, I mean write the first letter of a word in capital letter. The definition of "capitalization" in [Google](https://www.google.com/search?client=opera&q=capitalization+english+definition&sourceid=opera&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8) is this:

> the action of writing or printing in capital letters or with an initial capital.

When I look for the definition in Spanish:

> Acción de capitalizar.

I get only the finance definition.

I am thinking to use "mayúsculación", but that sounds weird. I do not know the correct translate. **I would like to know that**.

Thanks for reading :D.

Comment: There is not a single word for this concept in Spanish. I would use phrases such as "escribir en mayúsculas" or "uso de mayúsculas" depending on context.